# Worker vs data class

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a data class which encapsulates relevant data items in it. Those data items are set and get by users one by one when needed.

My confusion about the design has to do with which object should be responsible for handling the update of multiple properties of that data object. Sometimes an update operation will be performed which affects many properties at once.

So, which class should have the `update()` method?. Is it the data class itself or another manager class ? The `update()` method requires data exchange with many different objects, so I don't want to make it a member of the data class because I believe it should know nothing about the other objects required for update. I want the data class to be only a data-structure. Am I thinking wrong? What would be the right approach?

**My code:**

```
class RefData
{
    Matrix mX;
    Vector mV;


    int mA;
    bool mB;

    getX();

    setB();

    update(); // which affects almost any member attributes in the class, but requires many relations with many different classes, which makes this class dependant on them.

}
```

or,

```
class RefDataUpdater
{
   update(RefData*); // something like this ?
}
```

Comment: This grossly violates the principle of enforcing a class invariant and suggests the OO design is fundamentally flawed.  Perhaps you are putting too much unrelated data into one data structure.

Comment: @Amardeep -- What violates the principle of enforcing a class invariant?  It seems to me that bethoven25 is suggesting two ways of doing the OO design: one with the update method in the Data Object and one with it in a separate object.  Which is the better approach--seems to be a different discussion than how many properties an object has.  I agree that the properties a class has should be closely related--and that there are problems in the design, but can you elaborate?

Comment: The very first line of his posting is the crux of the problem.  If every data item is externally adjustable, there is no invariant.

Comment: @Amardeep Agree, but I think that is why the question is posed: should the update function be a member of the data class--or should the data class basically be a data structure? Perhaps I'm reading it wrong.  I've added an answer below, perhaps you can comment or help me clarify.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're boarding on the edge of some design principle(s) and/or design pattern(s) but without some more details about what it is you're trying to achieve this questions is in my opinion too general to answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is this really great section in the book [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), by Robert C. Martin, that speaks directly to this issue.

And the answer is *it depends*.  It depends on what you are trying to accomplish in your design--and
if you might have more than one data-object that exhibit similar behaviors.

First, your data class could be considered a *Data Transfer Object* (**DTO**).  As such, its ideal form is simply a class without any public methods--only public properties -- basically a data structure.  It will not encapsulate any behavior, it simply groups together related data.  Since other objects manipulate these data objects, if you were to add a property to the data object, you'd need to change all the other objects that have functions that now need to access that new property.  However, on the flip side, if you added a new function to a manager class, you need to make zero changes to the data object class.

So, I think often you want to think about how many data objects might have an update function that relates directly to the properties of that class.  If you have 5 classes that contain 3-4 properties but all have an update function, then I'd lean toward having the update function be part of the "data-class" (which is more of an OO-design).  But, if you have one data-class in which it is likely to have properties added to it in the future, then I'd lean toward the **DTO** design (object as a data structure)--which is more procedural (requiring other functions to manipulate it) but still can be part of an otherwise Object Oriented architecture.

All this being said, as Robert Martin points out in the book:

> There are ways around this that are well known to experienced
>   object-oriented designers: VISITOR, or dual-dispatch, for example. 
>   But these techniques carry costs of their own and generally return the
>   structure to that of a procedural program.

Now, in the code you show, you have properties with types of Vector, and Matrix, which are probably more complex types than a simple DTO would contain, so you may want to think about what those represent and whether they could be moved to separate classes--with different functions to manipulate--as you typically would not expose a Matrix or a Vector directly as a property, but encapsulate them.

Answer (score 2):

As already written, it depends, but I'd probably go with an external support class that handles the update.

For once, I'd like to know why you'd use such a method? I believe it's safe to assume that the class doesn't only call setter methods for a list of parameters it receives, but I'll consider this case as well

**1) the trivial updater method**
In this case I mean something like this:

```
public update(a, b, c)
{
    setA(a);
    setB(b);
    setC(c);
}
```

In this case I'd probably not use such a method at all, I'd either define a macro for it or I'd call the setter themselves. But if it must be a method, then I'd place it inside the data class.

**2) the complex updater method**
The method in this case doesn't only contain calls to setters, but it also contains logic. If the logic is some sort of simple property update logic I'd try to put that logic inside the setters (that's what they are for in the first place), but if the logic involves multiple properties I'd put this logic inside an external supporting class (or a business logic class if any appropriate already there) since it's not a great idea having logic reside inside data classes.

Developing clear code that can be easily understood is very important and it's my belief that by putting logic of any kind (except for say setter logic) inside data classes won't help you achieving that.

**Edit**
I just though I'd add something else. Where to put such methods also depend upon your class and what purpose it fulfills. If we're talking for instance about Business/Domain Object classes, and we're not using an `Anemic Domain Model` these classes are allowed (and should contain) behavior/logic.

On the other hand, if this data class is say an `Entity` (persistence objects) which is not used in the `Domain Model` as well (complex `Domain Model`) I would strongly advice against placing logic inside them. The same goes for data classes which "feel" like pure data objects (more like structs), don't pollute them, keep the logic outside.

I guess like everywhere in software, there's no silver bullet and the right answer is: it depends (upon the classes, what this `update` method is doing, what's the architecture behind the application and other application specific considerations).